# how do I echo out a string if the_meta() is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

Want to echo out POA if the user doesn't add the custom field, how can this be achieved?

I would also like to add a £ before the_meta() so the user doesnt have to add this everytime, how can this be done?

```
<?php if ( ! the_meta() ) {
                echo'POA';
            } else {
                £ the_meta();
            }?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe: `echo "£" . the_meta();`?

Comment: I have set up a custom field for each post that adds a price to the post when I insert <?php the_meta() ?> into content.php this in turn inserts the markup <ul><li>MY PRICE</li></ul> into the post if a price is entered. If a price isn't entered however I would like to add default text 'POA' so that there is something there in place of the price?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
<?php

    $price = the_meta();

    if(!$price) {
        echo 'POA'; // No price
    }
    else {
        echo '£ ' . $price;
    }

?>
```

Comment: doing this seems to add the price + POA if the user adds the price custom field?

Comment: Hum... What is `the_meta()` function? It `echo()` or `return` a value?

Answer (score -1):

I don't sure what you want to do, but..

```
<?php if (!the_meta()):
            echo'POA';
        else:?>
            £ <?php the_meta();
        endif;?>
```